# Graph Api Permission to Read Email

Tags: c#, .net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following c# code. I am trying to read email in exchange 365 using graph api as per the following link

[Reading user emails using MS Graph API C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55311762/reading-user-emails-using-ms-graph-api-c-sharp)

```
 IConfidentialClientApplication cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                  .Create("myAppId")
                  .WithTenantId("myTenantId")
                  .WithClientSecret("myClientSecret")
                  .Build();
            ClientCredentialProvider ccp = new ClientCredentialProvider(cca);
            GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(ccp);

  var users = await client.Users.Request()
                             .GetAsync();
```

I executed it and got the following error:

> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: 'Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
> Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I have given the mail.read and user.read permission as per screenshot.
[image]

[image]

any advices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code shows, you use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) which uses **application permissions**.

If you want to use `var users = await client.Users.Request().GetAsync();` to list users, one of the application permissions need to be set.

[image]